# In Git, how to commit file once, but ignore further changes to the file

Tags: git

I have a log file `errors.log` which the software uses to report errors. The software does not create `errors.log` by itself, so the file must exist before hand.

The problem is, if I add it to `.gitignore` then developers would need to create it manually on their machines. If I don't ignore it, then each developer would be committing their own `errors.log` contents after testing... proving a large hassle when merging.

How do I make it so that new developers acquire a blank copy of `errors.log` when they initially clone it, but it is not added to working tree (regardless of changes) when `git add -A` is used?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't. Devs only need to create the file once per clone, that doesn't seem like a major hardship, but you could add a script to do it for them.

Comment: Note that setting one of the index flag bits (`--assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree`) must be done in *every* clone. That's *precisely as much work as creating the empty `errors.log` file*. You might as well just create the `errors.log` file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Update

The best way for this case is `skip-worktree`

skip-worktree, according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree/13631525#13631525) even where git knows that the file has been modified (or needs to be modified by a reset --hard or the like), it will pretend it has not been, using the version from the index instead. This persists until the index is discarded.

Another option, `assume-unchanged` is designed for cases where it is expensive to check whether a group of files have been modified

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged FILE_NAME
```

and if you want to track the changes again use this command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Would each dev need to run this after their original clone? Is there no 'automatic' way for the repo to assume this after cloned?

Comment: I updated the answer acording the new information, so yes, there is a better way, and it is using skip-worktree :)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the `skip-worktree` feature (and not `assume-unchanged`) like described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/717372